# how to create opengl 3.x or 4.x context with fltk 1.3?

Tags: opengl, fltk

I am considering porting one of my softwares from opengl 2.1 to modern versions (3.x or 4.x).

The GUI is designed with fltk, and includes a FL_GL_Window where I do all the rendering. Now my problem is that I do not understand how to specify the opengl context for this window.

If I would use SDL to create the OpenGL context, I could use something like:
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);

Is there something similar for fltk ? Or can it handle only Opengl 2.1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Neither [FLTK 1.1](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.1/Fl_Gl_Window.html#Fl_Gl_Window.Fl_Gl_Window) nor [FLTX 2.0](http://www.fltk.org/doc-2.0/html/classfltk_1_1GlWindow.html)'s window creation functions allow the creation of a *core* OpenGL context. You can still create a [compatibility context](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts) of post 2.1 versions (though not on MacOSX, where they only offer core OpenGL).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can use `WGL_ARB_create_context` or `wglCreateContext` to create an OpenGL context, and after that you can use Fl_GL_Window's [void context (void *, int destroy_flag=0)](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__Gl__Window.html#a446db213805423decdd02e3e71b922c5)  method to set the context. Ofcourse, you must be careful about creation. Luckilly, FLTK will be able to give you details about DC so you can create valid OpenGL context. Also, you can use `void* context()` method to get a point of the OpenGL context in use by FLTK.

Comment: OK, so the context must be created outside of FLTK, right ? I will have to create it differently for different systems (Windows and Linux).

Comment: The default one should be created for you (by Fl_GL_window), if you want something else, you must make it yourself it seems. Makes sense to me (I am not an OpenGL expert)...